# jqGrid Taking Long Time For Large Records

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, jqgrid

I am using jgGrid. Its working perfectly but when i pass about 90,000 records and open the page in google chrome it takes around 8 sec to create a grid which in my case it should be near 3-4 sec. and moreover when i run the same page on IE it became unresponsive.

Any suggestion how can i reduce the time ?

my script

```
function GetCommodityGrid(array) {
 array = array.rows; // assign rows array to array object
totalRows = array.length;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: array,
            colNames: ['COM_NAME', 'COM_CODE', 'DELV_UNITS', 'LOT_SIZE', 'TICK_SIZE', 'TICK_VALUE'],
            colModel: [
        { name: 'COM_NAME', index: 'COM_NAME', width: 90, editable: true },
        { name: 'COM_CODE', index: 'COM_CODE', width: 100, editable: true },
        { name: 'DELV_UNITS', index: 'DELV_UNITS', width: 80, align: "right", editable: true },
        { name: 'LOT_SIZE', index: 'LOT_SIZE', width: 80, align: "right", editable: true },
        { name: 'TICK_SIZE', index: 'TICK_SIZE', width: 80, align: "right", editable: true },
        { name: 'TICK_VALUE', index: 'TICK_VALUE', width: 150, sortable: false, editable: true }
    ],

            rowList: [50,100,200],
            rownumbers: true, // show the numbers on rows
            loadonce: true,
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'COM_NAME',
            viewrecords: true, // show the total records on the end of the page
            editurl: "TestGrid/EditRecord",
            caption: "JSON Example",

            //new option

           gridview: true,
           autoencode: true,

        });


        $("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { add: false },
    { //the Edit options
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        afterSubmit: function (response) {
            // you should return from server OK in sucess, any other message on error
            alert("after Submit");
            if (response.responseText == "OKK") {
                alert("Update is succefully")
                return [true, "", ""]
            }
            else {
                alert("Update failed")
                $("#cData").click();
                return [false, "", ""]
            }
        }
    });



    });
}
```

Comment: probably there are some other callbacks (`loadComplete` or `gridCompleate` which you not posted here)?

Comment: @Oleg no i did not subscribe any load complete or gridcomplete event.

Comment: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I analysed process of loading local grid with 90,000 unsorted rows and have found very funny bottleneck which one can easy overcome. First of all [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/performane-90000_.htm) is the demo which works quickly and [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/performane-90000.htm) is almost the same demo which works much slowly especially in IE.

The most time of loading jqGrid get [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L770-L875) of jqGrid code directly at the beggining:

```js
var p = $.extend(true,{
    // there are here different default values of jqGrid parameters
}, $.jgrid.defaults, pin || {});
```

Because one uses `true` as the first parameter then jQuery makes full copy of the data and it works slowly (why? It's another pure jQuery question).

As a workaround I suggest to set no `data` parameter during creating the grid. In the case the default parameter `data: []` will be used. Instead of that one can set `data` inside of `onInitGrid` callback:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    //data: gridData,
    datatype: "local",
    ....
    onInitGrid: function () {
        // get reference to parameters
        var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");

        // set data parameter
        p.data = gridData;
    }
});
```

As the result the performance of loading of the grid will become much better.

I will post later my suggestions to trirand how to make small change of the code of jqGrid to improve the performance of jqGrid in the case. What I suggest is very simple. One can save `data` parameter in a variable, then call `var p = $.extend(true,{...});` and then set `data` parameter directly in `p` variable

```
    // save local data array in temporary variable and remove from input parameters
    // to improve performance
    var localData;
    if (pin != null && pin.data !== undefined) {
        localData = pin.data;
        pin.data = [];
    }
    var p = $.extend(true,{
        // there are here different default values of jqGrid parameters
    }, $.jgrid.defaults, pin || {});
    if (localData !== undefined) {
        p.data = localData;
    }
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/performane-90000__.htm) uses [the fixed code of jqGrid](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-NotExtendLocalData.js) and it works quickly.

**UPDATED**: [The pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/635) which I posted to trirand is already [merged](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/3d35ec01e6d703aeddf9113ffb48694b6df431ce) to the main code of jqGrid on github (see more in [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/improving-performance-of-loading-local-data-in-jqgrid)). So the next version of jqGrid (version higher as 4.6.0) won't have the described problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading `JqGrid` as on demand, i.e load smaller chunk of data at one time instead of all data and load remaining data on pagination.

**Here is a sample code for reference**

PHP with MySQL

```
...
$page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page

$limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid

$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort

$sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction

if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

// connect to the database    
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword)
or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());    

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error conecting to db.");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM invheader a, clients b WHERE a.client_id=b.client_id");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

$count = $row['count'];    

if( $count >0 ) {
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
    $total_pages = 0;    
}

if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)

if ($start<0) $start = 0;

$SQL = "SELECT a.id, a.invdate, b.name, a.amount,a.tax,a.total,a.note FROM invheader a, clients b WHERE a.client_id=b.client_id ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";

$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldnt execute query.".mysql_error());

$responce->page = $page;

$responce->total = $total_pages;

$responce->records = $count;

$i=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $responce->rows[$i]=$responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[id],$row[invdate],$row[name],$row[amount],$row[tax],$row[total],$row[note]);

    $i++;
} 

echo $json->encode($responce); // coment if php 5
//echo json_encode($responce);
...
```

Comment: but my requirement is to get all data at once.